# How should a project manager tell his team that there are too many bugs?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, project-management

I remembered that our project manager told us that we had too many bugs in our products and he got into problems because of it, and he let us know about our frustration and even went as far as to raise his voice. Is this professional behavior, is this widespread in the industry? I feel like this isn't behavior that should be encouraged. How should a person talk without sounding like he's scolding people?

Comment: For instance: "there are too many bugs, why is that, and how can we improve"

Comment: Is this about new bugs introduced or open bugs that don't get fixed?

Comment: new bugs introduced

Comment: Who makes the decisions around the priorities of new features, maintenance work, and developers upskilling themselves? Who decides when a version is good enough to release?

Comment: Are there too many bugs?  Why?  Shouldn't even be on the PM to tell the team there are too many bugs, the team should figure that out themselves

Answer (score 4):

There's two factors in here.

1. The PM is frustrated with the quality of the code.
2. The PM is (apparently) on the hook for any defects that the developers introduce.

Obviously, shouting is unprofessional.  You're not rambunctious kindergartners, and you're not going to respond well to being shouted at since you're a whole adult.

But the other factor to this is that, it's not like the development team isn't aware of the bugs.  Everyone on the team may know of the defects, and no one likes putting out less than optimal work.

The project manager needs to work *with* their development team to resolve the bugs.  They are on the same team and working to the same goal.  Putting this on one side versus the other is not ideal since it's really placing blame for the fact that there are defects, or significant defects.  It could be the classic balancing act of a project having more feature requests rather than the bandwidth to fix bugs.

So...the PM working with the team is ideal and professional.  What this PM did is very much not.

Comment: "shouting" is not necessarily the result of "raising the voice". Just talking with some energy is not shouting. IMO

Comment: @virolino:  Telling people that "the code has too many bugs" in an elevated tone is tantamount to shouting, IMO.  How else am I meant to interpret such a message?

Comment: additionally, OP clarified that the team actually "implements" new bugs daily. So not only that old bugs do not get fixed, but new ones appear. The chance of success of the project is practically zero because the team is the opposite of your assumption: *"no one likes putting out less than optimal work"*. Actually, they are a lot worse barely optimal, they are destructive of the project. Quote from comments: *Is this about new bugs introduced or open bugs that don't get fixed?* – Helena; *new bugs introduced* – 
informant (informant is OP)

Comment: @virolino:  Having worked as a contractor before as well as a principle engineer, I say with confidence that the Devil is in the details.  Putting out bugs doesn't mean that people are *happy* about doing it.  They may simply not have a choice in the matter.  If the customer wants this feature more than they want these bugs fixed, then the bugs don't get fixed and the customer gets their feature.  In a utopia, everyone's happy.  But this is clearly not the case since the volume of bugs that are being pushed out outmode the value of the features the team is delivering.

Comment: "Devil is in the details" - totally agree. "Putting out bugs doesn't mean that people are happy about doing it." - but it does not mean that they are sad about it either. About everything else, it is just assumptions, we have really no information.

Answer (score 2):

Raising a voice is *generally* unprofessional.

But in the same breath, we are all human.

It really does depend on the scale of the issue(s) - say for example a bug cost the companies significant amounts of money (Hundreds of Thousands or Millions) - then yeah, a yelling might be somewhat justified.

Comment: Do you get to be more unprofessional the more severe an issue?

Comment: Do you get to be? Ideally, no. "Your jobs are on the line here, and I need to make that decision real soon now" should be as effective as shouting, it if comes to that. But under severe provocation, it can be hard to stay professional.

Comment: I'd also suggest that the manager investigate what kinds of mistakes are being made, and see if there is a root cause that can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of information in this question, and a lot of nuances.

> How should a project manager tell his team that there are too many bugs?

Repeatedly :) Until people get it.

> I remembered that our project manager told us that we had too many bugs in our products and he got into problems because of it

That is a bad company. PM should not have to pay for the incompetence of whoever is working.

> he let us know about our frustration and even went as far as to raise his voice.

Now this is ambiguous:

- did he just talk with energy? Explaining how the project is nosediving because of the poor work?
- or did he just screamed impolite epithets at you for the bad job you were doing?

If he just put energy in his words, that is just fine - as long as he did not put too much energy.

Using bad words is bad in any context, no other comment about it.

> Is this professional behavior, is this widespread in the industry? I feel like this isn't behavior that should be encouraged.

We do not know exactly hat happened, so we cannot tell if it was professional or not.

> How should a person talk without sounding like he's scolding people?

If people deserve to be scolded, then people should be scolded. No negotiation.

The only thing that matters is how the scolding is done. It has to be done with facts (e.g., statistics extracted from the bug tracker) and with roadmaps for improvement.

If there is no improvement at the end of the roadmap, scolding by terminating the work contract is the best way to go.

---

Just for amusement: why did you and your colleagues "implement" so many bugs for such a long time, that your project became a top priority in your company, to the point that the PM got in trouble?

---

Note: If the PM would ask a question, I would explain the steps between no-action-done and end-the employment-contract.

Answer (score 1):

Yelling is not ok in general and definitely not in a professional environment.

If the issue is that there's too many bugs that should not exist, then there are steps that can be taken to help reduce the number of bugs being generated. I'll elaborate further below.

If the issue is that other work cannot be done because of bugs taking up time, then that is a separate issue. Bugs are not the problem here, the lack of resources is. Bugs just happen to be using up some of those previous resources.
If this is the case, then you need more resources. It might take some time to get the new hires up to speed and contributing well, but that's something that the manager should've considered months ago when considering if they had enough resources for upcoming projects. that's not your problem, that's theirs. Not your fault if the manager can't manage.

Back to the issue of too many bugs. There's a lot of tooling around and processes that exist just to prevent the likelihood of bugs cropping up and prevent bug fixes from causing more bugs.

This could be using languages with extra features like strong typing (e.g. typescript instead of plain javascript)

This could even be done by making tools that take away tedious error-prone work. Like synchronizing controllers and api clients between front end and back end.

It could also be via increased use of unit tests and integration tests. If there isn't enough time to write unit tests and integration tests, then the problem becomes a resource issue again.
From my own experience writing good unit tests takes a lot of time. And learning how to use the tooling such as mocking utilities is its own endeavor. But that just takes time to learn. Time is a resource that can be allocated by your manager. Also include the time it takes to write the unit tests in the time estimate for tickets.

The main hidden benefit of unit testing is that is sort of forces other parties to actually contribute. So many bugs are caused by the person asking for a bad feature without thinking it through. Requiring information for unit tests forces people to think things through a bit more than just surface level considerations and actually leads to the edge cases that cause the bugs to happen.

Code reviews are also extremely important. Similar to the unit tests this takes up time, so this also needs to be accounted for when sizing tickets. But by writing code reviews you allow multiple developers to be exposed to the same code with different perspectives. Maybe someone familiar with other parts of the system will pick up on bugs earlier.

If I had to pick 1 of these things to implement in isolation I'd say to try and implement unit testing. This way you can ask for examples of the end result and validate that your code reaches that result and that when you do bug fixes later on that you don't suddenly break existing functionality. And it also forces all parties involved to actually think about the problem being solved and this usually starts useful discussions about the solution.

Comment: Not sure I agree with this "Bugs are not the problem here, the lack of resources is".  They could have plenty of resources but those resources are creating too many bugs because they aren't doing a good job,  It could be the wrong resources instead of not enough

Answer (score -1):

Edit: It doesn't do any good to tell a software team that they have too many bugs because the team is not in position to make the real changes needed to reduce the number of bugs. It is also a failure of the PM's management because it is the PM's job to manage the fixing of the bugs by assigning the correct person to do each bug, provide the languages, tools, QA staff, and proper review process. Yelling doesn't help, period.

Every software product has bugs in it. Every software shipped has bugs. The release process is partly figuring out if the bugs left in the product are acceptable for right now.

However, the job of a project manager is to allocate resources to fix the high priority bugs. That there are too many bugs to ship a product on some schedule is not something that can be easily fixed.

Bugs in software need a plan for fixing. Elements in that plan can include:

- Choice of language. For example, switching to Rust instead of C will remove a lot of bugs.
- Does the team have tools to help find bugs?
- How a bug is processed - is it given to someone who has the experience to know how to fix it? Is the QA process integrated into the bug fix so that developers get fast response time? Does the team have a trained QA person?
- Is enough time given for the bug fix?
- Are developers treated as a team working together on the product or are they handed bugs to deal with individually? It is often that individual developers can generate a bug fix that causes bugs elsewhere. Is there an architect that can review bug fixes to make sure that they work with the whole?
- Is the sales driven release plan realistic? If not, how will that tension be resolved? A number of places don't have hard release dates but review the existing bug list and determine if the release is possible or to hold back.

Without having a clear plan, bugs will proliferate.

Edit: All that a PM can do is to ask the team if they can work more hours. If that is not possible, then the PM needs to ask for more resources or push back on the schedule.

Comment: I mean, this is a good roadmap on how to *handle* bugs, but it doesn't really convey how  the PM should explain to the team that there are "too many".  To be honest, some amount of bugs may be accepted as low risk versus the timeline of the feature.  Switching languages may also not be a solution since the team may only know or be equipped to work in one language.  (Also Rust isn't just a magic bullet here. It's a good language but it's not magical.)

Comment: @Makoto the PM should not explain to the team that there are too many. "Too many bugs" is not the team's problem, that is management's problem.

Comment: ...but that's what the question is asking for.  In this chain one can infer that leadership is talking to the PM and they're relaying the message about the quantity of bugs, and the PM is relaying that to the team.  Somewhere, someone accepted the risk of one too many bugs or didn't realize the consequences of accepting one too many bugs, and that can fall into the duties of the PM to facilitate conversations of.

Comment: @Makoto The PM can ask for extra time from the developers. But if the developers can't give more time, then the PM has to either get more resources or push back on the schedule. Last night, I had a chat with a plant manager where he was talking about the bugs that his people were making. He was putting together a plan to change how operations were done so that the people would make fewer bugs. Bugs need a plan, not yelling, to fix. Getting the right bugs fixed is a management issue, not an individual person issue.

Comment: You seem to be fighting me on this, as opposed to making it clear to the OP.  The OP is asking for a better way for the PM to explain to the team that there are too many bugs.  Your answer doesn't address that or address why it's not the PM's responsibility to do so.

Answer (score -4):

> How should a project manager tell his team that they are too many bugs?

By telling the team there are too many bugs.

If they have been told before, they may need to be told more emphatically.  People do sometimes need to be yelled at, but it shouldn't be the first option.  If the team delivered good code they wouldn't get scolded.

A good leader will penetrate why there are bugs, which frankly are typically either bad specifications or bad unit testing.

Comment: "People do sometimes need to be yelled at" - 
In a pub fight maybe, but not in a professional settings.

Comment: @TigerGuy: firing people for incompetence (too many bugs can be regarded as incompetence) is still more professional than yelling / screaming. Of course, there are gradual steps between no reaction at all and firing someone. Note: fire = cancel job contract, not kill by shotgun.